# ReactJS changing the content of a div from onClick() event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a conceptual problem. Here follows the "pseudocode" where a chart of temperature forecast is displayed along with a button next to it. I want to make it such that whenever the button is clicked the temperature forecast chart changes to a forecast precipitation chart, and vice-versa.

#### App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DataFetcher from './fetch_data.js';
import { graphBuilderTemperature, changeGraph } from './helper_functions.js';

let graphState = "temp";

function App() {
   const { weather, forecastWeather } = DataFetcher();
   return (
      <main>
         //(... a bunch of div parents and siblings here)
          <div className="forecast_graph">
             {graphBuilderTemperature(forecastWeather)}
             <button className="forecast_graph_reload" onClick={() => changeGraph(forecastWeather, graphState)}></button>
          </div>
      </main>
   )
}
```

#### helper_functions.js

```
 //Function that returns a `BarChart` element. From the ReactJs Rechart library for generating charts.
export const graphBuilderTemperature = (forecastWeather) => {
   //(...)
      
   return (
      <BarChart
         //(... temperature forecast chart)
      </BarChart>
   )
 }

export const graphBuilderPrecipitation= (forecastWeather) => {
   //(...)
      
   return (
      <BarChart
         //(... precipitation forecast chart)
      </BarChart>
   )
 }

//function that executes `onClick()` which should change the chart displayed
export const changeGraph = (forecastWeather, graphState) => {
    if(graphState === "temp") {
        graphState = "precipitation"; 
        return (graphBuilderPrecipitation(forecastWeather));
    }else {
        graphState = "temp"; 
        return (graphBuilderTemperature(forecastWeather));
    }
}
```

Currently, the code reaches inside the respective function calls with `onClick()`, but whenever the new div element containing the new chart is returned, it is not displayed(updated) on my screen through the react component `App()` return.

---

It seems that I am making some conceptual mistake here. I am not sure how to return an element from the `onClick()` method, from within the return of the main react component class. Sorry in advance for the irreproducibility of the code.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong, or how could I achieve what I am looking after?

Comment: Do you want to display two components based on a condition? If yes then this can be made a lot simpler.

Comment: Your `changeGraph` function returns the proper compiled graph, but it doesn't render it anywhere. Maybe you need one more function that calls the `changeGraph` and loads it into your `div className="forcast_graph"`

Comment: @CVerica Yeah I suppose that's what's happening. But the precise issue is that I don't understand how to render the new chart onto the old chart in my `div className="forecast_graph"`. How could an additional function help?

Comment: Have you tried making the info `state` and then using a conditional if statement to switch between them? Like: `<div>{condition ? state1 : state2}</div>`

Comment: Everyone here beat me to it, but yeah, I also noticed you weren't using state at all. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is due to the fact that your app isn't re-rendering. React apps re-render when there's a change in the state of the app.

You can try to use `useState()` to determine which type of graph needs to be displayed and your button would toggle between both graph types.

```
const [graphType, setGraphType] = useState("temp")

const changeGraph = () => {
    graphType === "temp" ? setGraphType("precipitations") : setGraphType("temp")
}
```

Then in your App component, where you want to display your graphs, you could do something like this:

```
{graphType === "temp"? graphBuilderTemperature(forecastWeather) : graphBuilderPrecipitation(forecastWeather) }
```

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)